# Crop an image to smaller size from left to right and top to bottom using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, crop

I have an image 315x581. I want to crop it in 28x28 from top left to bottom right, then I need to save each 28x28 image in folder.
I could crop just one image from y1=0 to y2=28 and x1=0 to x2=28.

First problem is: I used cv2.imwrite("cropped.jpg", cropped) to save this small image, but It doesn't save it, provided that it works some line above.

Second problem is: How can I write a code which it keeps on cropping the image in 28x28 from left to right and top to bottom and save each subimage.
I used for loop, but I don't know how to complete it. 
Thank you so much for any help.

Here this is my code,

```js
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import PIL.Image
import os
import gzip
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
#%%

image1LL='C:/Users/Tala/Documents/PythonProjects/Poster-OpenCV-MaskXray/CHNCXR_0001_0_LL.jpg'
mask1LL='C:/Users/Tala/Documents/PythonProjects/Poster-OpenCV-MaskXray/CHNCXR_0001_0_threshLL.jpg'
#finalsSave='C:/Users/Tala/Documents/PythonProjects/Poster-OpenCV-MaskXray/Xray Result'

# load the image
img = cv2.imread(image1LL,0)
mask = cv2.imread(mask1LL,0)

# combine foreground+background
final1LL = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)

cv2.imshow('final1LL',final1LL)
cv2.waitKey(100)
final1LL.size
final1LL.shape

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite('final1LL.jpg',final1LL)

# crop the image using array slices -- it's a NumPy array
# after all!

y1=0
x1=0
for y2 in range(0,580,28):
    for x2 in range(0,314,28):
       cropped = final1LL[0:28, 0:28]
       cv2.imshow('cropped', cropped)
       cv2.waitKey(100)
       cv2.imwrite("cropped.jpg", cropped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good, but there is some fine tuning required. The following code will help you:

```
import cv2

filename = 'p1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename, 1)

interval = 100
stride = 100
count = 0
print img.shape

for i in range(0, img.shape[0], interval):
    for j in range(0, img.shape[1], interval):
        print j
        cropped_img = img[j:j + stride, i:i + stride]  #--- Notice this part where you have to add the stride as well ---
        count += 1
        cv2.imwrite('cropped_image_' + str(count) + '_.jpg', cropped_img)   #--- Also take note of how you would save all the cropped images by incrementing the count variable ---

cv2.waitKey()
```

### My result:

**Original image:**

[image]

#### Some of the cropped images:

**Cropped image 1**

[image]

**Cropped image 2**

[image]

**Cropped image 3**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. this code works good, but that was not what I was looking for. I figure out that I need to use another logic to cut the image. I used "click_and_crop" code to crop and save the cropped image with specific label in my folder. However, Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in PyTorch as a deep learning framework, then this task would be quite easy and can be done without the need for any other external image processing libraries such as OpenCV. The below code will convert a single image into a stack of multiple images in a form of PyTorch tensor. If you want to use only images then you need to remove the line "transforms.ToTensor()" and save the "tens" variable in the code as an image using matplotlib.

Note: Here bird image is used with dimension 32 x 32 x 3, crop images 5x5x3 with stride =1.

```
image = Image.open('bird.png')
tensreal = trans(image)
trans = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(32),
                        transforms.ToTensor(),
                        ])
stride = 1
crop_height = 5
crop_width = 5
img_height = 32
img_width = 32
tens_list = []
for i in range(0,img_width-crop_width,stride):
    for j in range(0,img_height-crop_height ,stride):
        tens = trans(image)
        tens1 =  tens[:, j:j+crop_height, i:i+crop_width]
        tens_list.append(tens1)          
all_tens = torch.stack(tens_list)
print(all_tens.size())
```